# On hover how can I make my child border overlap the parent border?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent with red border. When the user hovers on children, I am trying to change the children's border to overlap the parent. How can I achieve this?

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.parent a {
  display:block;
  padding:1em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}

.parent a:hover{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#">2</a>
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <a href="#">4</a>
      <a href="#">5</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So long as you know the width of the borders and are able to use relative positioning... I have exaggerated the borders here for clarity.

```
.parent {
  border:5px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.parent a {
  display:block;
  padding:1em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

.parent a:hover{
  border:5px solid #ddd;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kd0gf31z/

Comment: This is a more direct answer of the question but the other answer is good too.

Comment: Are you sure using relative positioning is a must for this solution. Without relative also it works:https://jsfiddle.net/xuwzschv/

Answer (score 14):

I made some changes on your style:

```
.parent{
  display:inline-block;
}

.parent a {
  display:block;
  padding:1em;
  border-right:1px solid red;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: none;
}

.parent a:first-of-type{
  border-top:1px solid red;
}

.parent a:last-of-type{
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}

.parent a:hover{
  border-color:#ddd;
}
```

see the result here https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/343ydvhs/

Comment: Can you add the border radius on top and bottom of parent?

Comment: of course, we can add it to the first and last child 

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/343ydvhs/1/

Answer (score 7):

You could achieve this through the use of absolutely positioned pseudo elements, like so:

```css
*,*::before,*::after{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;}
.parent{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
}
.parent a{
    display:block;
    padding:1em;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    position:relative;
}
.parent a:last-child{
    border:0;
}
.parent a:hover::after{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    bottom:-1px;
    content:"";
    left:-1px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-1px;
    top:-1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.parent a:hover{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  width:120%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lmwp0e7/

Something like this?

Comment: I want to hide the red border on hover

Answer (score -2):

Why not just change the parent CSS on the child hover?

```
.parent a:hover .parent {
//Some CSS
}
```

Comment: Did you test this yourself first? There are no parent selectors in CSS.

Comment: This would change the descendant of `a` with a class of `parent` but that doesn't exist.